# Beginner to simulating communications systems of space missions. I have GMAT, MATLAB and NASA's SPICE library. Where would I start?

Tags: communication, mission-design, simulation, gmat, spice

I recently managed to load SPICE kernels into GMAT to simulate the trajectories of real missions, and got its MATLAB interface working (still trying to understand how to use the two software together). I've also installed the Satellite Communications and Antenna Toolboxes for MATLAB and am learning how to use them and what their different functions do. Finally, I've been familiarizing myself with NASA's SPICE toolkit and I've noticed that they have kernels relating to spacecraft/rover/orbiter antennas and other instruments, which I assume would be used to simulate the communications systems of the missions.

So now I'm trying to figure out how to use these resources to simulate communications systems of orbiter missions (later I will try rovers and landers too) and derive various metrics/measurements from them and experiment with different configurations. However, I can't find much online (ChatGPT and Bing Chat aren't being very helpful either). Are there any tutorials, sites or other resources I could use to learn how to do this?